Llama-3.2-3b model finetuning for vqa loss not converging
I am trying to make a video question answering model trained on tgif qa dataset. I am using XCLIP as my video Embedding generator [ sampling 16 frames] and then my decoder is llama 3.2 3b . I am using a fcc / mlp for my connective adapter i.e. to map out video Embeddings to llama Embedding . Now my loss is just oscillating near 2 it is not decreasing. I have used lr scheduler and warm up steps but still my loss is oscillating . What should I do ? My guess is the mlp is not able to map out the Embeddings properly.
Should I change my Connective Adapter?
